# UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency Error - App keep crashing

Tags: objective-c, xcode

> 2012-04-18 12:58:07.108 MYiPad[12574:c07] Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency, reason: A
>   view can only be associated with at most one view controller at a
>   time! View < UITableView: 0xb0eae00; frame = (0 0; 320 960);
>   clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = < NSArray:
>   0xac460e0>; layer = < CALayer: 0xac46830>; contentOffset: {-0, -20}>
>   is associated with < RootViewController: 0xac20f20 >. Clear this
>   association before associating this view with .
>
> First throw call stack: (0x1b57012 0x153ce7e 0x1b56deb 0x4cf309
>   0x5665ac 0x562a90 0x6b0232 0x4e257 0x21e3f 0x184a8c 0x19c417d 0x1836d2
>   0xc4c2 0x1aae59 0x1a8f22 0x1aa16a 0x1a8edd 0x1a9055 0xf6338 0x1e64a81
>   0x1e63d33 0x1ea1e3a 0x1af98fd 0x1ea24bc 0x1ea2435 0x1d8c3a0 0x1adaf3f
>   0x1ada96f 0x1afd734 0x1afcf44 0x1afce1b 0x24917e3 0x2491668 0x48165c
>   0x2c8d 0x2bc5 0x1) libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an
>   exception

*- (void)viewDidLoad {

```
[self.tableView initWithFrame:self.tableView.frame style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
self.appDelegate = (FCDBiPadAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[self.tableView setBackgroundView:nil];
[self.tableView setBackgroundView:[[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease]];
[self.tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:217 green:220 blue:225 alpha:0.9]];
unsigned int b;
NSScanner *scanner = [[NSScanner alloc] initWithString:[[[Engine sharedInstance] properties] objectForKey:@"NAVBAR_COL"]];
[scanner scanHexInt:&b];
[scanner release];  
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor blackColor];
//self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor=UIColorFromRGB(b);
views = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];  
NSMutableArray *innerArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[innerArray addObject:@"Login"];

txnlist = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[txnlist addObject:@"RRLGN00"];
NSMutableDictionary *menu1Dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:innerArray forKey:@"MENU"];
[menu1Dict setObject:txnlist forKey:@"MENUKEY"];
[views addObject:menu1Dict];
Engine *myEngine = [Engine sharedInstance];

**[myEngine setTableview:self.tableView];**
[myEngine settableData:self.views];


[super viewDidLoad];
self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320.0, 600.0);
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = TRUE;
```

}*

I keep getting this error and i cannot figure out what is it that i am doing wrong. My nib file, i am using a split view controller. Root view controller that handles the menu and a detail view controller that handles the detail (obviously) . When I comment out this line     **[myEngine setTableview:self.tableView];**
the app would run and i would not get the UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency error however the menu would not load as i am commenting it out. Someone please help me, i need this asap, my life depends on it. thanks again.

EDITED----

*- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [[Engine sharedInstance] setmenu_curr:@"RRLGN00"];
    [[Engine sharedInstance] setProperties:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"app.plist"]]]];

```
[[[Engine sharedInstance] properties] setObject:NSLocalizedString(@"FCDB_LANGID", nil) forKey:@"idLang"];

[[Engine sharedInstance] setUrl:[[[[Engine sharedInstance] properties] objectForKey:@"ENTITY_URL"] objectAtIndex:0]];
splashController = [[SplashViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SplashViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
splashController.delegate=self;
[self.window addSubview:splashController.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
```

}
- (void)hideSplash{
    [splashController.view removeFromSuperview];

```
self.splitViewController =[[UISplitViewController alloc]init];
self.rootViewController=[[RootViewController alloc]init];
self.detailViewController=[[DetailViewController alloc]init];
UINavigationController *rootNav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];
UINavigationController *detailNav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:detailViewController];
//detailNav.navigationBarHidden=YES;
self.splitViewController.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:rootNav,detailViewController,nil];
self.splitViewController.delegate=detailViewController;
[window addSubview:self.splitViewController.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

}*

I hear what you are saying but i think im doing something very simple wrong, or some simple adjustment. The above code is from my app delegate.

I checked this website out http://www.iriphon.com/2012/03/31/uncaught-exception-uiviewcontrollerhierarchyinconsistency-reason-child-view-controller-should-have-parent-view-controller-but-actual-parent-is-or-apples-new-uiviewcontroller-hierarc/

and i think it may have to do with what im doing. I may be wrong, if i am, please tell me.

Comment: dont know if im interpresting this correctly, but am i having two view controllers pointing to the same view in the lines.. self.splitViewController.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:rootNav,detailViewController,nil];
self.splitViewController.delegate=detailViewController;
[window addSubview:self.splitViewController.view];

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you everything you need to know. A view can only belong to the view controller that it was originally created for.

I'm guessing that `Engine` is a subclass of `UIViewController`, either that or `Engine` contains a view controller. In the `-setTableview:` method, I'm guessing that you add the table view to that view controller somehow.

NOTE: If you really need this table view to be a part of `Engine`, you will need to completely sever the connection with `RootViewController`. In practice, I've never seen this done.

P.S. `[super viewDidLoad]` should be the very first thing you call from `-viewDidLoad`.

---

**Comments for your updated code**

*NOTE: I don't think this will solve your problem, but it's the correct way to set window.*

Don't use `[self.window addSubview:splashController.view]` and `[window addSubview:self.splitViewController.view]`. Instead it should be `self.window. rootViewController = splashController` and `self.window.rootViewController = self.splitViewController`.

Comment: I edited the post above and added some more code, please take a look and let me know what you think. thanks.

Comment: dont know if im interpresting this correctly, but am i having two view controllers pointing to the same view in the lines.. self.splitViewController.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:rootNav,detailViewController,nil]; self.splitViewController.delegate=detailViewController; [window addSubview:self.splitViewController.view];

Comment: @Sonic I'm not sure what you are trying to point out. `self.splitViewController.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:rootNav,detailViewController,nil]` is a controller pointing at sub-view controllers (legit). `self.splitViewController.delegate=detailViewController` is setting a delegate (legit). `[window addSubview:self.splitViewController.view]` is the code I already commented on.

Comment: @Sonic I didn't think it would. I'm still guessing the problem is in `-[Engine setTableview:]`. Could you post the code for that?